# Create binary string ending in n 1

Tags: php, math, binary

This is quite basic, but I don't know where to begin. I'd like to write a function so that `function nBits(integer $i)` retruns a binary string ending in n 1.

```
0 => 00000000 => chr(0)    
4 => 00001111 => chr(15)
6 => 00111111 => chr(63)
```

This function would do it, but I feel, it is inefficient.

```
function ($n){
    $val = pow(2, $n) - 1;
    return chr($val);
}
```

How could I achieve the same thing more efficiently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid functions when basic operators work:

```
$val = (1<<$n) - 1;
return chr($val);
```